# What is the best way to cast a type to a List in the View of an MVC program?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, casting

So I want to set the ListView to hold an ObservableList in my View. My Model is a Module type. Currently, I'm importing the Model which isn't MVC compliant.

How would I do this without importing the Model? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really what I wanted but my current solution to my question was just to cast everything as an *Object* or *?* where applicable.